# Ignore Failed Data From The Given List When Global Spring Exception Handler is Enabled

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Consider a scenario where we have to run a loop with 10 messages. During the iteration if the 5th message fails because of some exception, request routed to Global Exception Handler. Because of this the rest of the messages are not processed.

How to handle the exception is this scenario, as well as skip the ones which are failing because of some exception and process rest of the messages.

> Global Exception Handler Using Spring

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerUtil
{

    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger( ExceptionHandlerUtil.class.getPackage().getName() );

    @ExceptionHandler( Exception.class )
    public @ResponseBody ExceptionDTO commonExceptionHandler( Exception e , HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException, JSONException
        {
            LOGGER.log( Level.SEVERE , FullHistoryUtil.printException( e ) );
            ExceptionDTO exceptionDTO = new ExceptionDTO();
            exceptionDTO.setStatus( 500 );
            exceptionDTO.setMessage( e.toString() );
            response.setStatus( 500 );
            NotificationServiceImplementation notificationService = new NotificationServiceImplementation();
            notificationService.sendExceptionNotification( e , request , 86400 , true );
            return exceptionDTO;
        }
```

> Our Controller

```
@RequestMapping( value = “/messages/bulk” , method = RequestMethod.POST , consumes = "application/json; charset=utf-8" )
    public @ResponseBody InteractionResponseDTO persistInteraction( @RequestBody String interactionJSON , HttpServletRequest request )  throws JSONException , IOException , IllegalAccessException , InvocationTargetException , UnprocessableEntityException
        {
            return interaction.persistInteractionService( interactionJSON , request );
        }
```

Consider inside **persistInteractionService** I am iterating a list which has 10 messages. But 5th message threw some exception, control goes to global exception handler. I am not able to run the rest of the messages (i.e.., from 6 to 10 ).

Comment: Can you provide some code for reference?

Comment: @noiaverbale provided some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to *collect* those exception in your service method.

I would define a custom exception able to collect any exception inside your for loop and then throw it only if it has collected any.

A sample implementation could be somthing as follow:

**IteractionMultiException.java**

```java
public class IteractionMultiException extends Exception {
    private final Map<IntegrationMessage, Exception> exceptions = new HashMap<>();

    public void addException(IntegrationMessage message, Exception exception) {
        exceptions.put(message, exception);
    }

    public boolean hasCatched() {
        return exceptions.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

**persistInteractionService method**

```java
public InteractionResponseDTO persistInteractionService(String interactionJSON , HttpServletRequest request) {
    IteractionMultiException multiException = new IteractionMultiException();
    InteractionResponseDTO response = null;

    Collection<IntegrationMessage> integrationMessages = getIntegrationMessages(interactionJSON);
    for (IntegrationMessage message : integrationMessages) {
        try {
            // your logic here
        } catch(Exception e) {
            multiException.addException(message, e);
        }
    }

    if (multiException.hasCatched()) {
        throw multiException;
    }

    return response;
}
```

This solution may vary a lot depending on the logic of your service, but I hope it's what you're looking for.